# Code compliance - how do I pass EMT conduit through an interior wall?

Tags: wiring, conduit

I live in Fairfax, Virginia.  I need to know how to pass 1/2 inch EMT conduit through an interior wall while complying with code.  In more detail, I have a subpanel in an attached garage.  From that subpanel, I plan on adding three circuits -- two circuits for outlets inside the garage, and one circuit for an outdoor outlet.  All are being done with surface mounted outlets and surface mounted 1/2 inch EMT conduit, using THHN wire.  For the outdoor outlet, I plan on running the EMT conduit to the back wall of the garage, and then through the garage back wall into an adjoining storage closet.  After another about six feet of EMT conduit in the closet, I will transition the THHN wire to a short length (couple inches) of outdoor Romex in an interior junction box before penetrating the exterior wall to mount the exterior outlet.  The storage closet has doors that open only to outside of the house, it is not a closet inside the house.  What are my options to pass the conduit through that interior wall?

Comment: There's no magic to it, really. Office buildings all over the U.S. have EMT simply punched through both layers of drywall and fire-taped or caulked.

Comment: I agree a razor knife, hammer, drill or a sheetrock saw ,will all work check the area for power prior to cutting it you might find a hot wire. Many stud finders have a voltage detect function for under 20$.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no magic here

Conduits can simply go through drywall at will, as they're legal to use for both exposed and concealed applications.  If this were a penetration of the house-garage fire barrier, I would firestop it with an appropriate caulking product for the application, but since it's not, simply jabbing the conduit through a saw-cut hole in the drywall will do the trick.  Don't forget to double-check to make sure you aren't about to try to run the EMT *through* something other than drywall though!